# Insert string before file extension in another string

Tags: c++, insert

I'm trying to insert a string into another string like you would with `append()` but rather than at the end I'd like to put it before the occurrence of ".xlsx".

```
    string docName;
    docName = "../Toyota Tacoma " + customer.toStdString() + " .xlsx";
    if(sold = true){
        docName = docName.append("(sold)");
    }
    doc.CreateDocument(docName);
```

This code just appends "(sold)" after ".xlsx"

Comment: My guess would be that `sold = true` is supposed to be `sold == true`. Or just `if(sold)`

Comment: Also `docName.append()` will already append to the string, no need to assign it to `docName` again.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply rewrite the code a bit, such that you do not have to insert at all:

```
string docName;
docName = "../Toyota Tacoma " + customer.toStdString();
if(sold == true){
    docName += "(sold)";
}
docName += ".xlsx";
doc.CreateDocument(docName);
```